# justify content center outer margin auto not aligning outer

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

with justify-content:flex-start, margin 0 auto not working for centering outer div

tried to make content start from left in each row with justify-content:flex-start items and outer div horizontal center to align this container in center of page

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:1200px;width:100%">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap new-cards justify-content-between">
            
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>
            <div class="card  p-3">Lorem em ipsum dolor sem ipsum dolor sem ipsum dolor sipsum dolorem ipsum dolor s sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aliquid, mollitia odio veniam sit iste esse assumenda amet aperiam exercitationem, ea animi blanditiis recusandae! Ratione voluptatum molestiae adipisci, beatae obcaecati.</div>

         </div>  </div>
```

tried to center justify-content-start to make it's outer center in page

Answer (score -1):

**Use this code**
In your outer div then your inner div vertically and horizontally center

```
 <div class="d-flex  align-items-center" style="margin:0 auto; max-width:1200px; height:100vh; width:100%">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).